# webservice login using ZF2

Tags: php, web-services, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have a webservice module configured with json strategy. I am making a login functionality where if the user is not logged return an error.

To test if the user is logged have an event dispatch on Module class

```
class Module {
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e) {
    (...)

    $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH, array($this, 'mvcPreDispatch'), 1000);
}

public function mvcPreDispatch(MvcEvent $e) {
    $authService = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('auth');
    if($authService->isAuthenticated()) {
        return true;
    }

    $model = new JsonModel(array(
        'errors' => array(
            'httpCode' => $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode(),
            'title' => $e->getResponse()->getReasonPhrase(),
            'message' => 'Login necessário'
        )
    ));

    return $model;
}
}
```

How can I stop the request and display the error message on the screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik you need to short circuit the event by returning a `Response` object or by calling `stopPropagation(true)` on the event. This will stop all other dispatch listeners from executing and return a response to the client.

You can try something like this:

```
public function mvcPreDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $authService = $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('auth');
    if($authService->isAuthenticated()) {
        return true;
    }

    $model = new JsonModel(array(
        'errors' => array(
            'httpCode' => $e->getResponse()->getStatusCode(),
            'title' => $e->getResponse()->getReasonPhrase(),
            'message' => 'Login necessário'
        )
    ));
    $e->setViewModel($model);
    $e->stopPropagation(true);
}
```